# How and where do I use the data from an Apollo Client?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

How and where do I have to put that query so that I can map through it and display the categories in a header. I'm a noob and all the apollo documentation is made with hooks and functional components, but I have to do this assignment with class based components and I just can't figure it out.

index.js:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <>
         <Header />
       </>
     );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Header.js:

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header>
        <ul className="nav-list">
           //Display categories here with map in a <li className="nav-item">
        </ul>
     </header>
     )
  }
}
```

query I need for header elements :

```
       const QUERY = gql`
         query getCategories {
            categories {
                name
             }
         }
       `;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooks don't work with class components - **but** you can wrap your class components and pass the hook result as props to the class component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useScreenWidth } from '../hooks/useScreenWidth';

export const withQueryHOC = (Component, query) => {
  return (props) => {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(query);

    return <Component loading={loading} error={error} data={data} {...props} />;
  };
};
```

This is called a [Higher-Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Where `Component` is the class component you want to wrap. This way you can use class components but still have access to the hooks.

You should export you component like so:

```
export default withQueryHOC(YourComponentHere);
```

In your component you should access `loading`, `error` and `data` through `this.props`